# Do these Zariski-dense subgroups of $\operatorname{SO}_{6}(\mathbb C)$ have non-empty intersection with this subset?

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups, zariski-topology

Let $G\leq \operatorname{SO}_{6}(\mathbb Z)$ be a finite-index normal subgroup, so it's a Zariski dense subgroup of $\operatorname{SO}_{6}(\mathbb C)$; and let $H$ be the subset of $\operatorname{SO}_{6}(\mathbb C)$ given by
$$
H=\left\{e_{x,y}= \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & y \\
 \frac{1}{y} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{x} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\middle| x,y\in\mathbb C^* \right\}.
$$

Let $B=B(\mathbb{C})$ be the Borel subgroup which consists of upper triangular matrices.

> Is it true that $G\cap Be_{1,1}B$ is necessarily non-empty?

As noticed in the comments, $G\cap H$ is empty for most congruence subgroups $G$.

Here $\operatorname{SO}_{n}(k)$ is defined as $\{A\in\operatorname{GL}_{n}(k)\mid A^TJ_nA=J_n\}$,
where $J_n$ is the identity matrix flipped 90 degrees.

My progress:
I've been trying to study this subset of $Be_{1,1}B\cap\operatorname{SO}_{6}(\mathbb Z)$:
$$
L=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
 b_{1} & b_{3} & 1 & a_{2} b_{3}+a_{1} b_{1} & a_{3} b_{1}-a_{2} & -a_{3} b_{3}-a_{1} \\
 b_{2} & 0 & 0 & a_{1} b_{2}-b_{3} & a_{3} b_{2}+1 & 0 \\
 0 & -b_{2} & 0 & -a_{2} b_{2}-b_{1} & 0 & a_{3} b_{2}+1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & a_{1} & a_{3} & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & a_{2} & 0 & -a_{3} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \middle| a_i,b_i\in\mathbb Z\right\}.
$$

I noticed that the characteristic polynomials of the matrices in $L$ are of the form $p_{a,b,c}(x)=1+ax+bx^2+cx^3+bx^4+ax^5+x^6$, maybe

> $ \{A\in \operatorname{SO}_{6}(\mathbb C)|\exists a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}\;\text{s.t.}\;p_{a,b,c}(x)=p_{\text{char}}(A)(x)\}\subset Be_{1,1}B$

Here:

- $p_{\text{char}}(A)(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

There is something similar in $\operatorname{SL}_{n}(\mathbb C)$ where instead of $e_{1,1}$ we take $e$ to be the permutation matrix of $(123..n)$ and $G$ a finite index normal subgroup of  $\operatorname{SL}_{n}(\mathbb Z)$ and $B$ the upper triangular matrices. Then since $J=\{A\in \operatorname{SL}_{n}(\mathbb C)|disc(A)\neq 0\}$ is Zariski open there is a $g\in J\cap G$ and since every element of $J$ is similar to some $b_1eb_2$ ,$b_i\in B$ , we get $g\in G\cap BeB$.

Here $disc(A)$ is the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial of A.

Comment: You can even take $G$ to be a "generic" Zariski dense 2-generated subgroup  in $SO_6({\mathbb C})$. Then the intersection with $H$ will be empty. Here generic means that the two generators are chosen generically.

Comment: @Misha thank you, I edited my question a bit.

Comment: You should look more closely at what's written and revise again: Since $G$ is supposed to have integer matrix entries, if the intersection is nonempty then $x=\pm 1, y=\pm 1$. Hence, $G\cap H=\emptyset$ for most congruence  subgroups. I am not sure what happens for double cosets with Borel.

Comment: Since your specific choice of $H$ (and the requirement that the upper-triangular matrices form a Borel subgroup) means that the form of $\operatorname{SO}_6$ matters, you should specify what form you use.

Comment: I use the definition $\operatorname{SO}_{2n}(k)=\{A\in\operatorname{GL}_{2n}(k)|A^TJ_{2n}A=J_{2n}\}$ where $J_{2n}$ is the identity matrix flipped 90 degrees

Comment: Clearly $H\cap\mathrm{GL}_6(\mathbf{Z})$ is finite (of cardinal $4$) and does not contain the identity matrix. Hence there is a finite index subgroup with empty intersection with $H$ (e.g., kernel of reduction modulo 2).

Comment: @YCor Thank you yes I did miss this simple fact as Misha pointed, in regards to the second question I believe that $Be_{1,1}B$ is a Bruhat cell (which is not the big cell)

Comment: Since (passing to a smaller finite index subgroup) you can suppose that $G$ is normal in $\mathrm{SO}_6(\mathbf{Z})$ (and hence normalized by $e_{1,1}$), you can write $G$ instead of $A^{-1}GA$ in your new question.

Comment: @YCor yes thanks.